# In VS2013 is there an easy way to update attributes in your model?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I'm using VS2013 in a MVC 5 app.  Created EF6 model using the database first approach which yielded the model as expected.  Subsequently I will make changes in the database objects (tables, views, stored procs).  When I go into the model to update it, the visible model will get updated.  Looking at the Model Browser, I have to manually clean up the artifacts that no longer exist.  Am I missing something in my procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you right click and update the model from the database, it will typically add new pieces automatically, but in my experience it doesn't automatically remove pieces that are no longer there, so you'll need to watch for those and delete them manually.

On the plus side, if you had any special customizations around a field (e.g. enum types), and the field gets renamed, this gives you a chance to compare the two configurations and make sure they line up before you delete the old field from your model.